# How to do linear transition and enlarge Animation By CAKeyframeAnimation?

Tags: swift, uikit, cabasicanimation, cakeyframeanimation, catransaction

I want to do a linear animation like this: move the rectangle slowly to center of Screen, and tripled its size while moving.

Here is my **wrong code** and **demo**, I can only do animation one by one, but I want to combine this two animation. Also, the end position is not right.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupUI()
        presentAnimation()
    }

    private lazy var rectView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .yellow
        view.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
        return view
    }()
}

extension ViewController {
    private func setupUI() {
        
        view.addSubview(rectView)
        rectView.snp.makeConstraints { 
            $0.left.equalToSuperview().inset(40)
            $0.top.equalToSuperview().inset(100)
            $0.width.equalTo(40)
            $0[![enter image description here][1]][1].height.equalTo(40)
        }
    }
    
    private func presentAnimation() {
        let testEnlarge = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.scale")
        testEnlarge.fromValue = 1
        testEnlarge.toValue = 3
        testEnlarge.beginTime = CACurrentMediaTime() + 2
        testEnlarge.duration = 1
        testEnlarge.fillMode = .forwards
        testEnlarge.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
        
        let positionX = view.center.x - ((rectView.frame.width * 3)/2)
        let positionY = view.center.y - ((rectView.frame.height * 3)/2)
        
        let testTranslation = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "transform.translation")
        testTranslation.values = [CGPoint(x: positionX, y: positionY)]
        testTranslation.beginTime = CACurrentMediaTime() + 2
        testEnlarge.duration = 1
        testEnlarge.fillMode = .forwards
        testTranslation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
        
        CATransaction.begin()
        rectView.layer.add(testEnlarge, forKey: nil)
        rectView.layer.add(testTranslation, forKey: nil)
        CATransaction.commit()
    }
}
Here is my **wrong demo**:
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your question, your code has two errors

First one: When you use `CAKeyframeAnimation` for translation, in `values` you must define list Array which contains startPoint -> endPoint.

```swift
// You must define start point is at the beginning (CGPointZero of view) to end is the destination point
testTranslation.values = [CGPointZero, CGPoint(x: positionX, y: positionY)]
```

Then after that your code will work OK but not good because of duplication and you can not control all animations like that.

Second error here is: When you want to combine two or more animations you should use `CAAnimationGroup` to combine then add into layer not adding once by once.

Code will be like this

```swift
private func presentAnimation() {
    let testEnlarge = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.scale")
    testEnlarge.fromValue = 1
    testEnlarge.toValue = 3
    testEnlarge.fillMode = .forwards
    
    let positionX = view.center.x - ((rectView.frame.width * 3)/2)
    let positionY = view.center.y - ((rectView.frame.height * 3)/2)
    
    let testTranslation = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "transform.translation")
    // you must define start point is at the beginning (CGPointZero of view) to end is the destination point
    testTranslation.values = [CGPointZero, CGPoint(x: positionX, y: positionY)]
    
    let sumAnimation = CAAnimationGroup()
    sumAnimation.animations = [testTranslation, testEnlarge]
    sumAnimation.duration = 1
    sumAnimation.beginTime = CACurrentMediaTime() + 2
    
    CATransaction.begin()
    rectView.layer.add(sumAnimation, forKey: nil)
    CATransaction.commit()
}
```

You will have like the result you want
[image: Result]

**More over**: you can use `UIView.animate` too.

Comment: by the way, if the rectView is a FLAnimatedImageView which has a gif animatedView. May I ask how to set the gif duration as the same of animation duration?

Comment: Dear @malcopolocei, I've never used like that but as far as I know you should attach gif animation as same duration as animation time than set in code.